# Is it possible to make the organization chart as follows with the organization chart (Balkan chart)?

Tags: orgchart

Is it possible to make the org chart like the image link below using Orgchart (Balkan Graph)?
Looking at the API I could not find a solution.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zQHyP8MDP9gkKvOAbSiKPmJObjIUCpn0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BALKANGraph](https://balkangraph.com/) developer evangelist here

Basically you need to tag 4 nodes with assistant tags

[image]

```js
 var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
            template: "ula",
            layout: BALKANGraph.mixed,
            nodeMenu: {
                pdf: { text: "Export PDF" },
                png: { text: "Export PNG" },
                svg: { text: "Export SVG" }
            },
            collapse: {
                level: 2
            },
            nodeBinding: {
                field_0: "name",
                field_1: "title",
                img_0: "img"
            },
            nodes: [
                { id: "1", name: "Jack Hill", title: "Chairman and CEO", email: "amber@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/1.jpg" },
                { id: "2", pid: "1", name: "Lexie Cole", title: "QA Lead", email: "ava@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/2.jpg" },
                { id: "3", pid: "1", name: "Janae Barrett", title: "Technical Director", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/3.jpg" },
                { id: "4", pid: "1", name: "Aaliyah Webb", title: "Manager", email: "jay@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/4.jpg" },
                { id: "5", pid: "2", name: "Elliot Ross", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/5.jpg" },
                { id: "6", pid: "2", name: "Anahi Gordon", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/6.jpg" },
                { id: "7", pid: "2", name: "Knox Macias", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/7.jpg" },
                { id: "8", pid: "3", name: "Nash Ingram", title: ".NET Team Lead", email: "kohen@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/8.jpg" },
                { id: "9", pid: "3", name: "Sage Barnett", title: "JS Team Lead", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/9.jpg" },
                { id: "10", pid: "8", name: "Alice Gray", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/10.jpg" },
                { id: "11", pid: "8", name: "Anne Ewing", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/11.jpg" },
                { id: "12", pid: "9", name: "Reuben Mcleod", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/12.jpg" },
                { id: "13", pid: "9", name: "Ariel Wiley", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/13.jpg" },
                { id: "14", pid: "4", name: "Lucas West", title: "Marketer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/14.jpg" },
                { id: "15", pid: "4", name: "Adan Travis", title: "Designer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/15.jpg" },
                { id: "16", pid: "4", name: "Alex Snider", title: "Sales Manager", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/16.jpg" },
                { id: "101", pid: "1", tags: ["assistant"], name: "Blair White", title: "Assitant", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/13.jpg" },
                { id: "102", pid: "1", tags: ["assistant"], name: "Nicky Fraser", title: "Assitant", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/14.jpg" },
                { id: "103", pid: "1", tags: ["assistant"], name: "Skyler Lewis", title: "Assitant", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/15.jpg" },
                { id: "104", pid: "1", tags: ["assistant"], name: "Gabby Cline", title: "Assitant", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/16.jpg" }

            ]
        });
```

```css
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }

        #tree {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .node.assistant line {
            stroke: #F57C00;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://balkangraph.com/js/latest/OrgChart.js"></script>

<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: How wonderful, thank you for the feedback, it worked perfectly.